# Play! 2.3.1 - main.css 404 (public assets not routing?)

Tags: playframework, http-status-code-404, assets

I just loaded the Play Java Seed from the UI to create a new app. I wrote some CSS code in `public/stylesheets/main.css`, and this is the only change I made to this project. After compiling and running the app, the Chrome console says

```
GET http://localhost:9000/assets/stylesheets/main.css 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:9000/assets/javascripts/hello.js 404 (Not Found)
```

I've read the Asset controller documentations [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.0/Assets) but cannot figure out where I'm going wrong.

In my `main.scala.html` file (unchanged from seed), I have:

```
<head>
    <title>@title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.at("images/favicon.png")">
    <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/hello.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

And in my routes file (also unchanged from seed):

```
# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

The favicon shows up in the tab, but when I go to `http://localhost:9000/assets/images/favicon.png`, the page is also not available, just like with main.css and the hello.js script.

Comment: Everything looks correct. How are you running your app? `activator run` or `activator start`...

Comment: I'm not sure. I was doing everything through the UI. I just ran it in the command line with `activator run` and now all files are loading correctly. Is this a problem with the UI?

In any case, thank you so much for the tip.

Comment: What version of `activator` you running and on what OS?

Comment: activator version 1.2.3 and OS X 10.8.5

Comment: having same issue upgrading my play 2.1 app to 2.3

Comment: I have this same issue. Any chance it is bug.

Comment: same issue on 2.3.7 with scala-seed project

Answer (score 2):

It also seems to happen (on play 2.3.8) when running from a packaged tarball created by:

```
$ activator universal:package-zip-tarball
```

, then..

```
$ [tarball-extract-path]/bin/[project-name]
```

On a local dev build the files download fine, but on remote test server I get 404 (Not found).

Comment: This is happening to me as well. I'm trying to deploy a recently 2.2->2.3 migrated project and every asset is 404ing.

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue disappears when i start my project for production:

```
activator start
```

This is just a workaround but i hope it helps some of you guy's.

I suspect this is a bug in play and will hopefully be gone on a new play version.

Comment: This is the solution.

Answer (score -1):

If you have `LessKeys.compress := true` on your build, you've to use a minified version.

`@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.min.css")`

Answer (score -2):

I have no issue with running **Play Java Seed** downloaded from [typesafe.com](http://typesafe.com/activator/template/play-java) which uses PlayFramework 2.3.7

Take a look what I did and do the same

```
$ unzip play-java.zip 
  Archive:  play-java.zip
  inflating: play-java/conf/application.conf  
  inflating: play-java/conf/routes   
  inflating: play-java/README        
  inflating: play-java/activator     
  inflating: play-java/app/views/main.scala.html  
  inflating: play-java/app/views/index.scala.html  
  inflating: play-java/app/controllers/Application.java  
  inflating: play-java/test/ApplicationTest.java  
  inflating: play-java/test/IntegrationTest.java  
  inflating: play-java/project/plugins.sbt  
  inflating: play-java/project/build.properties  
  inflating: play-java/LICENSE       
  inflating: play-java/.gitignore    
  inflating: play-java/public/stylesheets/main.css  
  inflating: play-java/public/javascripts/hello.js  
  inflating: play-java/public/images/favicon.png  
  inflating: play-java/build.sbt     
  inflating: play-java/activator.bat  
  inflating: play-java/activator-launch-1.2.12.jar  

$ cd play-java/

$ ls
activator*  activator.bat*  activator-launch-1.2.12.jar  app/  build.sbt  conf/  LICENSE      project/  public/  README  test/

$ activator run
[info] Loading project definition from /home/skierat/Documents/dev/projects/typesafe/play-java/project
[info] Updating {file:/home/skierat/Documents/dev/projects/typesafe/play-java/project/}play-java-build...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.3.7/jars/sbt-plugin.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.3.7!sbt-plugin.jar (3451ms)
[info] downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/build-link/2.3.7/build-link-2.3.7.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.play#build-link;2.3.7!build-link.jar (534ms)
[info] downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/play-exceptions/2.3.7/play-exceptions-2.3.7.jar ...                                                                                                         
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.play#play-exceptions;2.3.7!play-exceptions.jar (527ms)                                                                                                                                                   
[info] downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/routes-compiler_2.10/2.3.7/routes-compiler_2.10-2.3.7.jar ...                                                                                               
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.play#routes-compiler_2.10;2.3.7!routes-compiler_2.10.jar (2230ms)                                                                                                                                        
[info] downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/sbt-run-support_2.10/2.3.7/sbt-run-support_2.10-2.3.7.jar ...                                                                                               
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.play#sbt-run-support_2.10;2.3.7!sbt-run-support_2.10.jar (652ms)                                                                                                                                         
[info] Done updating.                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
[info] Set current project to play-java (in build file:/home/skierat/Documents/dev/projects/typesafe/play-java/)                                                                                                                            
[info] Updating {file:/home/skierat/Documents/dev/projects/typesafe/play-java/}root...                                                                                                                                                      
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.11 ...
[info] downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/play_2.11/2.3.7/play_2.11-2.3.7.jar ...                                                                                                                     
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.play#play_2.11;2.3.7!play_2.11.jar (6448ms)                                                                                                                                                              
[info] downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/play-java_2.11/2.3.7/play-java_2.11-2.3.7.jar ...                                                                                                           
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.play#play-java_2.11;2.3.7!play-java_2.11.jar (768ms)                                                                                                                                                     
[info] downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/play-java-jdbc_2.11/2.3.7/play-java-jdbc_2.11-2.3.7.jar ...                                                                                                 
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.play#play-java-jdbc_2.11;2.3.7!play-java-jdbc_2.11.jar (550ms)                                                                                                                                           
[info] downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/play-java-ebean_2.11/2.3.7/play-java-ebean_2.11-2.3.7.jar ...                                                                                               
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.play#play-java-ebean_2.11;2.3.7!play-java-ebean_2.11.jar (655ms)                                                                                                                                         
[info] downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/play-cache_2.11/2.3.7/play-cache_2.11-2.3.7.jar ...                                                                                                         
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.play#play-cache_2.11;2.3.7!play-cache_2.11.jar (775ms)
[info] downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/play-java-ws_2.11/2.3.7/play-java-ws_2.11-2.3.7.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.play#play-java-ws_2.11;2.3.7!play-java-ws_2.11.jar (661ms)
[info] downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/play-iteratees_2.11/2.3.7/play-iteratees_2.11-2.3.7.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.play#play-iteratees_2.11;2.3.7!play-iteratees_2.11.jar (4162ms)
[info] downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/play-json_2.11/2.3.7/play-json_2.11-2.3.7.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.play#play-json_2.11;2.3.7!play-json_2.11.jar (1627ms)
[info] downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/play-functional_2.11/2.3.7/play-functional_2.11-2.3.7.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.play#play-functional_2.11;2.3.7!play-functional_2.11.jar (1132ms)
[info] downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/play-datacommons_2.11/2.3.7/play-datacommons_2.11-2.3.7.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.play#play-datacommons_2.11;2.3.7!play-datacommons_2.11.jar (526ms)
[info] downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/play-jdbc_2.11/2.3.7/play-jdbc_2.11-2.3.7.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.play#play-jdbc_2.11;2.3.7!play-jdbc_2.11.jar (891ms)
[info] downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/play-ws_2.11/2.3.7/play-ws_2.11-2.3.7.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.play#play-ws_2.11;2.3.7!play-ws_2.11.jar (1746ms)
[info] downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/play-test_2.11/2.3.7/play-test_2.11-2.3.7.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.play#play-test_2.11;2.3.7!play-test_2.11.jar (773ms)
[info] downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/play-docs_2.11/2.3.7/play-docs_2.11-2.3.7.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.play#play-docs_2.11;2.3.7!play-docs_2.11.jar (8607ms)
[info] Done updating.

--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
```

And final test :

```
$ curl -Is http://localhost:9000/assets/stylesheets/main.css | head -n 1
```

returns

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```